What is the purpose of these long HTML ids?
I've received a spam email with an HTML body with every tag having a very long, unique id.
The document doesn't have an accompanying style sheet, and it doesn't have a style tag.
The ids appear to be machine generated?
What's the purpose of such a long tag?
<HTML>
<BODY>
<BR style="FONT-SIZE:small;FONT-FAMILY:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;WHITE-SPACE:normal;WORD-SPACING:0;TEXT-TRANSFORM:none;FONT-WEIGHT:400;COLOR:rgb(34,34,34);FONT-STYLE:normal;ORPHANS:2;WIDOWS:2;LETTER-SPACING:normal;TEXT-INDENT:0;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;-webkit-text-stroke-width:0;text-decoration-thickness:initial;text-decoration-style:initial;text-decoration-color:initial">
<TABLE id=m_-8984580946764443804m_-1455028683161535659m_7095573496303921127m_-2729946107681548217m_-8455065143803520220m_-4676213858292137014m_2129817230670973435m_5145104447712978886m_9012623916170356755m_6784990475732591730m_6712571582327446165m_3141984423244323055m_-4211660544643026039gmail-v1v1isxl style="BORDER-COLLAPSE:collapse" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" align=center bgColor=#eff2f7 border=0>
<TBODY id=m_-8984580946764443804m_-1455028683161535659m_7095573496303921127m_-2729946107681548217m_-8455065143803520220m_-4676213858292137014m_2129817230670973435m_5145104447712978886m_9012623916170356755m_6784990475732591730m_6712571582327446165m_3141984423244323055m_-4211660544643026039gmail-v1v1irvj>
<TR id=m_-8984580946764443804m_-1455028683161535659m_7095573496303921127m_-2729946107681548217m_-8455065143803520220m_-4676213858292137014m_2129817230670973435m_5145104447712978886m_9012623916170356755m_6784990475732591730m_6712571582327446165m_3141984423244323055m_-4211660544643026039gmail-v1v1i80t>
<TD id=m_-8984580946764443804m_-1455028683161535659m_7095573496303921127m_-2729946107681548217m_-8455065143803520220m_-4676213858292137014m_2129817230670973435m_5145104447712978886m_9012623916170356755m_6784990475732591730m_6712571582327446165m_3141984423244323055m_-4211660544643026039gmail-v1v1i9l4 style="MARGIN:0" height=30 vAlign=top align=center>
...


Guess: It could be to fool spam filters that match on the email contents, by making the HTML unique for each spam mail.

IDs can be arbitrarily long. Making them super long helps make them more likely to be unique if they're being generated programmatically. And style sheets aren't the only thing that can take advantage of IDs (hint: JavaScript)

Thanks @Dave-S and j08691 - I think this is it. Spam email was Base64 encoded too; probably another step in their obfuscation. Thanks for the insights. Can't mark those as Answers as they were just in the comments.
